# Dynamicaly Naming Columns - Using SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have query that that references a dynamic calander table, it updates aged periods based on the current date.  I am using this table in another query, it sum's sales value based on aged QTR's.  These values will update as time passes and I can assign colmn names such as 'AGED1Q' but I would like to find a way to use the actual period name from the calander table.  Any sugestions will be greatly appreciated.

Current query is below, I have added a few comment lines where I would like to make the changes.  Thanks again

```
    SELECT        dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID AS CUST_ID, 

              SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.QTRs_AGED = -4 THEN dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE.TOTAL_AMT_ORDERED ELSE 0 END) AS '-4', --As MAX(dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.QTR) WHERE dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.QTRs_AGED = -4 
              SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.QTRs_AGED = -3 THEN dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE.TOTAL_AMT_ORDERED ELSE 0 END) AS '-3', --As MAX(dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.QTR) WHERE dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.QTRs_AGED = -3
              SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.QTRs_AGED = -2 THEN dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE.TOTAL_AMT_ORDERED ELSE 0 END) AS '-2', --As MAX(dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.QTR) WHERE dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.QTRs_AGED = -2
              SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.QTRs_AGED = -1 THEN dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE.TOTAL_AMT_ORDERED ELSE 0 END) AS '-1', --As MAX(dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.QTR) WHERE dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.QTRs_AGED = -1
              SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.QTRs_AGED IN(-4, -3, -2, -1) THEN dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE.TOTAL_AMT_ORDERED ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL'

FROM            dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.UFC_Calander LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING ON dbo.UFC_Calander.DAY = dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.DATES ON 
                         dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.ORDER_DATE = dbo.UFC_Calander.DAY LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.CUSTOMER ON dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID = dbo.CUSTOMER.ID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.PART RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE ON dbo.PART.ID = dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID ON dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID = dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID

WHERE        (dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.STATUS <> 'x') AND dbo.UCC_CALENDAR_TODAY_BASED_AGING.QTRs_AGED IN(-4, -3, -2, -1)

GROUP BY dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID

HAVING        (dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID <> 'UNFOCO') AND (dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID <> 'QUOTE')
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

Comment: Learn to use alias.

Comment: You want to name the columns dynamically. In short: This is not allowed. The engine must know the structure of the resultset in advance. The only way around is *dynamic SQL* (Create the statement as string and use `EXEC()` for the execution. But this has some draw-backs too (e.g. no usage in views or (i)TVFs).